# gradle can not solve the ${com.mxx.stc} in the strings.xml

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

My `strings.xml`:

```
<bool name="debug_mode">${com.mxx.stc}</bool>
```

My `build.gradle`:

```
String debug_mode ="\\u0024\\u007Bcom.mxx.stc\\u007D"
def replaceInString = {variant, fromString, toString ->
            File valuesFile = file("${buildDir}/intermediates/res/${variant.dirName}/values/values.xml")
    println "Replacing revision number in " + valuesFile
    String content = valuesFile.getText('UTF-8')
    content = content.replaceAll(fromString, toString)
    valuesFile.write(content, 'UTF-8')
}
android.applicationVariants.all{ variant ->
    variant.mergeResources.doLast{
    replaceInString(variant,debug_mode ,"true")
}
```

Then gradle will show the error:

```
Error:(22, 29) String types not allowed (at 'debug_mode' with value '${com.mxx.stc}')
```

How do I solve the problem? Can I skip the error? By the way, if the placeholder is a string tag, gradle works fine.

Comment: Maybe Gradle has problems with processing string with special characters like $, { and }? Do you have to keep that format of String? If not, you can try to change it to something more regular like: commxxstc. Check if it works correctly with letters only. Next, you can try to add dots like: com.mxx.stc and check it again.

Comment: @piotr.wittchen thank you for you answer very much, I have find the reason that the file value.xml will not be updated by next gradle build. I deleted the value.xml and build again, Its done.